# React JSON правильно вернуть Render

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

Суть такая: По ссылке тягаю через JSON API с инстаграмма картинки.

```
import React from 'react';


const App = () => {
    var requestURL = 'https://www.instagram.com/p/BwA-ZlRhHxq/?__a=1';

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', requestURL);
    request.responseType = 'json';
    request.send();
    request.onload = function () {
        request.response['graphql']['shortcode_media']['edge_sidecar_to_children']['edges'].map((name) =>
            //<img src={name['node']['display_url']}/>
            console.log(name['node']['display_url'])
        )
    };

    return (
        <p>{request.response}</p>
        )
    };

export default App;
```

Если я помещаю

```
return (
    request.response['graphql']['shortcode_media']['edge_sidecar_to_children']['edges'].map((name) =>
        <img src={name['node']['display_url']}/>
    )
)
```

внуть onload, то появляется ошибка, что ничего не позвращает render...

А в данном случае `<p>{request.response}</p>` пустой. А если пытаться вывести картинки вне onload, то `request.response` - пустой...

Внутри onload если делать console.log, то все ссылки выбираются...
Что я делаю не так???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рендер перерисовывает компонент, только если изменился `state`, а этого у вас и не делается. В примере ниже: если `state.fetching = true` отображается лоадер, старт загрузки происходит в `componentDidMount()`, как только закачка завершилась, полученный массив помещаем в `state` (изменяя его) и ставим `fetching=false`. В итоге компонент перерисовывается с картинками

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      urls: [],
      fetching: true
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    let requestURL = 'https://www.instagram.com/p/BwA-ZlRhHxq/?__a=1';

    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', requestURL);
    request.responseType = 'json';
    request.onload = () => {
      this.setState({
        urls: request.response['graphql']['shortcode_media']['edge_sidecar_to_children']['edges'],
        fetching: false
      });
    };
    request.send();
  }
  
  render() {
    if(this.state.fetching) {
      return (
        <div className="spinner-border">
          <span className="sr-only">Loading...</span>
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    return this.state.urls.map(name => <img className="img-thumbnail mr-3 mb-3" src={name['node']['display_url']}/>);
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```css
img {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div id="root"></div>
```